# Can someone explain why i'm getting an infinite loop for my linked list and how to fix it?

Tags: c++, linked-list, infinite-loop

I'm new to C++ and i'm trying to write a method to add a node to the end of a linked list but i'm getting an infinite loop and i'm not sure why.

```
#include "Car.h"

Car::Car()
{
    this->pName = NULL;
    this->pNext = NULL;
}

Car::Car(const char *name)
{
    this->pName = name;
    this->pNext = NULL;
}
```

```
#include "Garage.h"

Garage::Garage()
{
    this->pHead = NULL;
}

void Garage::AddToFront(Car *r) 
{
    if (this->pHead != NULL) 
    {
        Car *tmp = this->pHead;
        this->pHead = r;
        r->pNext = tmp;
    }
    this->pHead = r;
}

void Garage::Print(const char *string)
{
    Trace::out("Garage(%s): \n",string);
    Car tmp = *pHead;
    while (tmp.pNext != NULL) 
    {
        Trace::out("\tCar(%s)--->%s \n", tmp.pName, tmp.pNext->pName);
        tmp = *tmp.pNext;
    }
    Trace::out("\tCar(%s)--->%s \n", tmp.pName, "(null)");
    Trace::out("\n");
}

void Garage::Remove(Car *r)
{
    Car *tmp = this->pHead;
    Car *prev = NULL;
    if (pHead == r)
    {
        pHead = r->pNext;
        return;
    }
    while (tmp != NULL && tmp != r)
    {
        prev = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->pNext;
    }
    prev->pNext = tmp->pNext;
}

void Garage::AddToEnd(Car *r)
{
    if (pHead == NULL)
    {
        pHead = r;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Car *tmp = pHead;
        while (tmp->pNext != NULL)
        {
            tmp = tmp->pNext;
        };
        tmp->pNext = r;
        return;
    }
}
```

```
int main()
{
    // -------------------------------------------------
    // Do not change the main() function in any way
    // -------------------------------------------------
    // Output needs to match PDF exactly
    //--------------------------------------------------

    Car A("Jetta");
    Car B("Accord");
    Car C("Forte");
    Car D("Outback");
    Car E("Escape");

    Garage G;

    G.AddToFront(&A);
    G.AddToFront(&B);
    G.AddToFront(&C);
    G.AddToFront(&D);
    G.AddToFront(&E);

    G.Print("Add to Front");

    G.Remove(&A);
    G.Remove(&C);
    G.Remove(&E);

    G.Print("Remove A,C,E");

    G.AddToEnd(&A);
    G.Print("After A");
    G.AddToEnd(&C);
    G.Print("After C");
    G.AddToEnd(&E);

    G.Print("Add to End");
```

I've tried debugging and printing my list but I can't figure out what to do. It looks like i've made my list circular but i'm not sure how I did this and how to fix it. I can post my header files too if that would be helpful to debugging this.

Comment: Drawing a linked list on a piece of paper should help.

Comment: When you remove a car, set that car's pNext to NULL.

Comment: Initialize ALL your variables, eg. pointers to `nullptr`. Side note about your design, a Garage is not a linked list  but is should use a linked list. Separation of concerns is a core principle of good design and you are not doing that. Making the list class first should allow you to test it independently.

Comment: @shr NO set it to `nullptr`

Comment: `NULL` is deprecated since 2011.

Comment: Thank you the nullptr really saved me, and I saw the error in me not initializing the next to null!

Comment: I'm curious, what reference book is recommending to use `this->` to access member variables and methods.  If you choose different names between parameters and members, you don't need the `this->` syntax.

Comment: @shr, a copy of the `car` field `next` should be made before it is set to nullptr, otherwise you'll loose a whole bunch of nodes, when you remove a node in the middle of a list.

Comment: A minor note: your constructors should use member initialization lists.

Comment: Your question starts nicely general about linked lists. The suddenly there is code for a `Car` class. Why? Keep the question simple. Don't show a linked list of `Car` objects; show a linked list of some fundamental type like `int` or of a trivial `struct Node {};`. *Keep in mind that we are not grading your homework, so the instructions of your assignment are not binding here.*

Comment: *"It looks like i've made my list circular but i'm not sure how I did this and how to fix it."* -- This is your interpretation of objective symptoms. Do you really trust your conclusions that much? It would be better to show the symptoms that lead you to this conclusion. And show just the symptoms, not your full solution. See [mre].

Comment: In function `Garage::Remove`, the loop `while (tmp != NULL && tmp != r)` can end because `tmp` is `nullptr`. In that case, it is UB (undefined behavior) to make the assignment `prev->pNext = tmp->pNext;`.

Comment: In function `Garage::AddToEnd`, you may need to set `r->pNext` to `nullptr`, unless, that is, the calling routine has already done so.

Comment: In function `Car::Car(const char *name)`, you only make a shallow copy of pointer `name`. Should that be a deep copy? One alternative would be to ditch the C-strings altogether, and use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain why I'm getting an infinite loop for my linked list and how to fix it?

The linked list in the OP is a brittle structure that depends on the the allocation of `Car` nodes in function `main`. Functions in struct `Garage` do not copy `Car` nodes when they are inserted into the `Garage` list. Instead, the `Garage` list simply stores pointers to the `Car` nodes that are allocated in function `main`.

When you remove `Car* r` from the `Garage` list, `r->pNext` continues to point into the `Garage` list.

When that same car is added back at the end of the list, you create a loop in the `Garage` list.

One way to fix both problems is to set `r->pNext` to `nullptr` when `Car* r` is removed from the `Garage` list.

Here is my version of function `Remove`. It calls helper function `FindPrev`, which, in all but a few special cases, returns a pointer to the node that precedes `Car* r` in the `Garage` list.

`FindPrev` returns `nullptr` when:

- The `Garage` list is empty.
- `Car* r` is not found in the `Garage` list.
- `Car* r` is found at the head of the `Garage` list.
- `r` is `nullptr`.

```cpp
Car* Garage::FindPrev(Car* r)
{
    if (r == nullptr || pHead == nullptr || r == pHead)
        return nullptr;
    Car* p{ pHead->pNext };
    Car* prev{ pHead };
    while (p != nullptr && p != r)
    {
        prev = p;
        p = p->pNext;
    }
    return p ? prev : nullptr;
}

void Garage::Remove(Car* r)
{
    if (r == nullptr || pHead == nullptr)
        return;
    else if (pHead == r)
    {
        pHead = pHead->pNext;
        r->pNext = nullptr;
    }
    else if (auto p{ FindPrev(r) }; p)
    {
        p->pNext = r->pNext;
        r->pNext = nullptr;
    }
}
```

As a precaution, function `AddToEnd` should set `r->pNext` to `nullptr`, as well. My version includes a check to see whether `Car* r` is `nullptr`.

```cpp
void Garage::AddToEnd(Car* r)
{
    if (r == nullptr)
        return;
    else if (pHead == nullptr)
    {
        pHead = r;
        r->pNext = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        Car* tmp = pHead;
        while (tmp->pNext != nullptr)
        {
            tmp = tmp->pNext;
        };
        tmp->pNext = r;
        r->pNext = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Incidentally, function `AddToFront` can be simplified. Once again, I have added a check to verify that `r` is not `nullptr`. You need that in all the functions that accept `r` as a parameter.

```cpp
void Garage::AddToFront(Car* r)
{
    if (r != nullptr)
    {
        r->pNext = pHead;
        pHead = r;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Garage(Add to Front):
        Car(Escape)--->Outback
        Car(Outback)--->Forte
        Car(Forte)--->Accord
        Car(Accord)--->Jetta
        Car(Jetta)--->(null)

Garage(Remove A,C,E):
        Car(Outback)--->Accord
        Car(Accord)--->(null)

Garage(After A):
        Car(Outback)--->Accord
        Car(Accord)--->Jetta
        Car(Jetta)--->(null)

Garage(After C):
        Car(Outback)--->Accord
        Car(Accord)--->Jetta
        Car(Jetta)--->Forte
        Car(Forte)--->(null)

Garage(Add to End):
        Car(Outback)--->Accord
        Car(Accord)--->Jetta
        Car(Jetta)--->Forte
        Car(Forte)--->Escape
        Car(Escape)--->(null)
```